# Cocoa System Services: Name of calling app

Tags: cocoa

First of all I would like to thank all of the contributors of this site. 
Now for the questions:

I have implemented a simple system service using the [System Services Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html) and posts on this site.
I would like to find out the name of the application that initiated the call to my service either in my `- (void)handleServices:(NSPasteboard *)pboard` or via some other means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application that initiated the call to your service has to be the most active.
So you can get information about it via NSWorkSpace:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activeApplication] valueForKey:@"NSApplicationName"] //  you might also be interested via @"NSApplicationBundleIdentifier
```

I just tested this with a very basic Service, and it works as expected.